# How can I improve my terrain generator's performance?

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate, terrain

My terrain generator I want to be fullscreen, but when I change block size, FPS decreases. How to fix this?

```py
pygame.init()

scsizeX = 600
scsizeY = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
scX, scY = screen.get_size()
clock = pygame.time.Clock ()
plrX = 300
plrY = 200
speed = 3
plrOri = "Right"
cameraX = 0
cameraY = 0
genSize = 100
gen = []
fonts = [pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 24)]
FPS = 1024
playerSize = 36
blockSize = 64
plrMoved = False
background_colour = (255,255,255)
clo = (255,255,0)

pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

playerimg = pygame.image.load('assets/player.png')
mouseimg = pygame.image.load('assets/mouse.png')
grassimg = pygame.image.load('assets/grass.png')
stoneimg = pygame.image.load('assets/stone.png')
grassimg = pygame.transform.scale(grassimg, (blockSize, blockSize))
stoneimg = pygame.transform.scale(stoneimg, (blockSize, blockSize))
mouseimg = pygame.transform.scale(mouseimg, (48, 48))
playerimg = pygame.transform.scale(playerimg, (playerSize * 2, playerSize * 2))

screen.fill(background_colour)

player = screen.blit(playerimg, (300, 200))
mouse = screen.blit(mouseimg, (300, 200))

for x in range(genSize):
    for y in range(genSize):
        g = random.randint(1,2)
        gen.append(g)

def block(tp, posX, posY):
    if tp == "grass":
        return screen.blit(grassimg, (posX - cameraX - playerSize, posY - cameraY - playerSize))
    elif tp == "stone":
        return screen.blit(stoneimg, (posX - cameraX - playerSize, posY - cameraY - playerSize))

def render(fnt, what, color, where):
    "Renders the fonts as passed from display_fps"
    text_to_show = fnt.render(what, 0, pygame.Color(color))
    screen.blit(text_to_show, where)

game = True
while game:

    screen.fill(background_colour)
    plrMoved = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game = False
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mouseimg = pygame.transform.scale(mouseimg, (44, 44))
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mouseimg = pygame.image.load('assets/mouse.png')
            mouseimg = pygame.transform.scale(mouseimg, (48, 48))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        plrY -= speed
        plrMoved = True
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        plrX -= speed
        plrMoved = True
        plrOri = "Left"
    if keys[pygame.K_s]:
        plrY += speed
        plrMoved = True
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        plrX += speed
        plrMoved = True
        plrOri = "Right"

    cameraX = plrX - (scsizeX / 2)
    cameraY = plrY - (scsizeY / 2)

    #player = screen.blit(playerimg, (plrX, plrY))

    #if plrMoved:
    for x in range(int(scX / blockSize) + 2):
        for y in range(int(scY / blockSize) + 3):
            g = gen[(floor(cameraX / blockSize) + x) + (floor(cameraY / blockSize) + y)]

            if g == 1:
                block("grass", (floor(cameraX / blockSize) + x) * blockSize, (floor(cameraY / blockSize) + y) * blockSize)
            elif g == 2:
                block("stone", (floor(cameraX / blockSize) + x) * blockSize, (floor(cameraY / blockSize) + y) * blockSize)

    p_pos = plrX - cameraX - playerSize, plrY - cameraY - playerSize,
    if plrOri == "Right":
        player = screen.blit(playerimg, p_pos)
    elif plrOri == "Left":
        player = screen.blit(pygame.transform.flip(playerimg, True, False), p_pos)

    Mx, My = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    msrct = mouseimg.get_rect()
    msrct = msrct.move((Mx, My))
    mouse = screen.blit(mouseimg, msrct)

    render(
        fonts[0],
        what=str(int(clock.get_fps())),
        color="white",
        where=(0, 0))

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

I tried to only update terrain when player is moving but FPS is still low and when I stop moving the screen gets white.

Comment: I'm just curious how many FPS do you have after applying my suggestions?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I got 47 FPS good but I mean The Terrain Generator in the Loop Is Causing That Problem How Can I Fix It? When A New Block Should Appear And Others Should Not Remove?

Comment: You'll need to redraw the blocks every time the camera moves, not just when a new block appears. So I don't see much of a chance to improve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the background *Surface* has the same format as the display *Surface*. Use [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) (or [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha)) to create a *Surface* that has the same pixel format. This improves performance when the background is, when the background is `blit` on  the display, because the formats are compatible and `blit` does not need to perform an implicit transformation:

```py
playerimg = pygame.image.load('assets/player.png').convert_alpha() 
mouseimg = pygame.image.load('assets/mouse.png').convert_alpha() 
grassimg = pygame.image.load('assets/grass.png').convert_alpha()
stoneimg = pygame.image.load('assets/stone.png').convert_alpha()
```

---

You can buy performance by paying with memory usage. Create a large [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface) with the complete map:

```py
game_map = pygame.Surface((genSize * 64, genSize*64))
for x in range(genSize):
    for y in range(genSize):
        g = random.randint(1,2)
        if g == 1:
            game_map.blit(grassimg, (x * 64, y * 64))
        elif g == 2:
            game_map.blit(stoneimg, (x * 64, y * 64))
```

[`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) the area which is currently visible on the screen:

```py
while game:
    # [...]

    map_sub_rect = screen.get_rect(topleft = (cameraX, cameraY))
    screen.blit(game_map, (0, 0), map_sub_rect)

    # [...]
```