# I'm making a little game on pygame, but I don't know why it's running so slow

Tags: python, pygame

Here is the main code for the game. It's basically just a shooter that moves vertically on the left of the screen. However, once I added in the aliens, the game just slowed down a lot, and is basically unplayable. What can I do to make it faster? I believe that the issue started once I added the aliens, maybe I have included something in the While loop that makes it work too hard every single loop? Because when I delete the self.aliens.draw(self.screen) the game works perfectly fine. I also tried changing the image for the aliens and it seems to work fine, could it be that the image is too high quality??

```
import pygame
import sys

from shooter_bien import Shooter
from shooter_bullet import Bullet
from alien_shooter import Alien

class SidewayShooter():
    """Class to manage game."""
    
    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize game and resources."""
        pygame.init()
        
        self.WID = 1200
        self.HEI = 700
        self.bg = pygame.image.load('bga.jpg')
        
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.WID, self.HEI))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Sideways Shooter")
        
        self.shooter = Shooter(self)
        self.bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.aliens = pygame.sprite.Group()     
        
        self._create_grid()   
        
    def run_game(self):
        """Main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_screen()
            self._update_bullets()
                        
            
    def _check_events(self):
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()
                
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                        sys.exit()
                    
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        self.shooter.moving_up = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        self.shooter.moving_down = True
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        self._create_bullet()
                
                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                        self.shooter.moving_up = False
                    if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                        self.shooter.moving_down = False
                        
    def _create_bullet(self):
        """Create new bullet and add to group."""
        bullet = Bullet(self)
        self.bullets.add(bullet)
    
    def _update_bullets(self):
        """Update bullets on screen and delete off screen."""
        self.bullets.update()
        
        for bullet in self.bullets.copy():
            if bullet.rect.right >= self.WID:
                self.bullets.remove(bullet)
    
    def _create_grid(self):
        """Create alien grid."""
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        
        amount_aliens_x = (self.WID // alien_width - 5) // 2
        amount_aliens_y = (self.HEI // alien_height) // 2
        
        for row_number in range(amount_aliens_x):
            for alien_number in range(amount_aliens_y):
                self._create_alien(alien_number, row_number)
        
    
    def _create_alien(self, alien_number, row_number):
        """Create an alien and add to grid."""
        alien = Alien(self)
        alien_width, alien_height = alien.rect.size
        
        alien.rect.centerx = (row_number + 3) * alien_width * 2
        alien.rect.centery = alien_number * alien_height * 2 + alien_height
        self.aliens.add(alien)
    
    def _update_screen(self):
        """Update bg and shooter."""
        self.screen.blit(self.bg, (0, 0))
        
        self.shooter.blitme()
        self.shooter.update()
        
        for bullet in self.bullets.sprites():
            bullet.draw_bullet()
        
        self.aliens.draw(self.screen)            
            
        pygame.display.flip()
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ss = SidewayShooter()
    ss.run_game()
```

Comment: Use [`convert()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert) and [`convert_alpha()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha). See [Lag when win.blit() background pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59312019/lag-when-win-blit-background-pygame/59318946#59318946) and [How Can I Improve My Terrain Generator Performance I Get 40 FPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66509002/how-can-i-improve-my-terrain-generator-performance-i-get-40-fps/66510253#66510253)

Comment: @Rabbid76 ohhh ok, so if both of them are the same type of file it will work smoother??

Comment: Try it! Do you load the bullet images in `Bullet.__init__`? This is a bad idea. Load the image once at the beginning and use the loaded  bullet _Surfaces_ when creating a new bullet.